# How to suspend inner Thread in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, methods

I have a component that some where inside it opens a thread to create Session,
I can not go in or change anything inside. 
I need to find a way to suspend the work till the inner Thread is finished. 
(Cant check if session created and therefor cant create loop to wait while !session)

```
public class Agenda {
Work work=new Work();
    public void go(){
        work.start();
    }

}
public class Work extends Thread {


    @Override
    public void run() {
    for(int i=0; i<10;++i)
        System.out.print("!->!");
    System.out.println("\n");   
    super.run();
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Hello SmartHead!!");
        Agenda agenda=new Agenda();
        agenda.go();
        //synchronized (work) {

        synchronized (agenda) {


        System.out.println("Finished !!! ");
    }

    }
    }
```

Comment: change `work.start()` to `work.run()` as you don't need to be using a background thread in the first place.

Comment: Did you mean you want to wait until thread created is finished? and then your main program can do the next program?

Comment: Unfortunately, if you can't change anything where the "inner" Thread is created you can't do much. One option could have been calling 'join' on the inner thread after starting it. Another could have been calling 'wait' from the "outer" Thread and 'notify' from the "inner" Thread on the same monitor object. But none is a viable option in your case as far as I understand.

Comment: That is exactly the issue , I cant change any thing in those components only external manipulations in Main.